# Random() assigns same values to new objects of same type

Tags: c#, random

I apologize for my not so well defined title, i found it hard to describe the issue in depth. I tried to research similar issues with `Random` across SO, and implemented the suggestions, however, without success.

I have the following code which simulates a sports tournament. The core of the logic lies in the Game class. When i simulate the tournament, the results assigned to the players in the games of the first round are fine, as in randomly assigned as intended. However, when i simulate round two and three and so on, the players who won the first round receive the exact same scores as they did in the first round. It's as if the system remembers them, instead of generating new random values. Im sure it has something to do with `Random`, but i cant wrap my head around it. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how i navigate around this issue?

RnDGen:

```
public class RndGen
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static int Get(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

Tournament:

```
public class Tournament : IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public List<Round> Rounds { get; set; }

    public GameMaster GameMaster { get; set; }

    public Tournament(string name, int year)
    {
        Rounds = new List<Round>();
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
    }

    public void Simulate(List<Player> players)
    {
        var playersStillInTournament = players;
        int roundNumber = 1;

        while (playersStillInTournament.Count > 1)
        {
            var round = new Round(roundNumber);

            round.Simulate(playersStillInTournament);
            playersStillInTournament = round.Winners;

            Rounds.Add(round);

            roundNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Round:

```
public class Round
{
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Winners => Games.Select(g => g.Winner).ToList();

    public Round(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
        Games = new List<Game>();
    }

    public void Simulate(List<Player> players)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != players.Count; i = i + 2)
        {
            var playersToAdd = players.Skip(i).Take(2).ToList();
            var game = new Game(playersToAdd);
            Games.Add(game);
        }
    }
}
```

Game:

```
public class Game
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; private set; }

    private int MaxSets => (Players.First().Gender == Gender.Male) ? 5 : 3;

    public Player Winner => Players.Find(p => p.SetPoints.Count(px => px == 6) == ((MaxSets + 2 - 1) / 2));

    public Game(List<Player> players)
    {
        Players = players;
        Simulate();
    }

    private void Simulate()
    {
        while (Winner == null)
        {
            var winnerId = Players[RndGen.Get(0, Players.Count)].Id;
            var loserPoints = RndGen.Get(0, 5);

             Players.Find(p => p.Id == winnerId).SetPoints.Add(6);
             Players.Find(p => p.Id != winnerId).SetPoints.Add(loserPoints);
        }
    }
}
```

Player

```
public class Player : Person
{
public List<int> SetPoints;

public int Points
{
    get
    {
        return SetPoints.Sum();
    }
}

public Player(string[] textFileLines, Gender gender)
    : base(textFileLines, gender)
{
    SetPoints = new List<int>();
}
```

Person

```
public abstract class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; } 

        public string FirstName { get; private set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; private set; }

        public string LastName { get; private set; } 

        public DateTime Birthday { get; private set; } 

        public string Country { get; private set; }

        public string CountryCode { get; private set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        // Returns the age as an integer
        public int GetAge => DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year;

        protected Person(string[] textFileLines, Gender gender)
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(textFileLines[0]);
            FirstName = textFileLines[1];
            MiddleName = textFileLines[2];
            LastName = textFileLines[3];
            Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(textFileLines[4]);
            Country = textFileLines[5];
            CountryCode = textFileLines[6];
            Gender = gender;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please include your code for `Player` class in your question so that it is easy to recreate.

Comment: I updated my question with Player and base class Person

Comment: It would be awesome if you could simplify the problem to be as short as possible to repro the issue. A [mcve] makes it much easier for us to help you. Your question, as is, has too much code in it.

Comment: I bet the problem is with "Winner == null" in Game.Simulate() but I don't see where do you instantiate Players. Maybe it isn't null.

Comment: Yes, please show us how you declare the players list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `Simulate()` to

```
private void Simulate()
{
    while (Winner == null)
    {
        var winnerId = Players[RndGen.Get(0, Players.Count)].Id;
        var loserPoints = RndGen.Get(0, 5);

            Players.Find(p => p.Id == winnerId).SetPoints.Add(6);
            Players.Find(p => p.Id != winnerId).SetPoints.Add(loserPoints);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Winner.Id);
    Players.ForEach(p => p.SetPoints = new List<int>());
}
```

So that you reset each player's `SetPoints` at the end of the round.

After running 5 simulations I got this output

```
5
2
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find a Winner in Game the while loop will not execute in the Simulate() method so the SetPoints will not change. When you run it again it will find the same winner again because Setpoints didn't change.